# Cannot read/write from/to plist on device, but can in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

i've been looking at a lot of posts with a similar problem here on Stackoverflow, but i still cannot figure out why i can't write/read my plist.
Here is my method to load my plist into the app. 
This should copy the plist to the device's *documents folder* and not *resources folder*, correct?

```
-(void)loadPlist:(NSString*)plistString {
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", plistString]];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:plistString ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@ already exists",path);
}
}
```

This is how i write to my plist:

```
-(void)writeScore:(NSString*)objectstring forPlayer:(int)playerTag {
switch (playerTag) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"Wrote to 1");
        holeInt = [P1hole_Label.text integerValue];
        plistpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Scores" ofType:@"plist"];
        plistdata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistpath];
        [plistdata setObject:[NSString stringWithString:objectstring] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hole %i", holeInt]];
        [plistdata writeToFile:plistpath atomically:YES];
        break; 
Etc.
```

And here is how i read the plist:

```
-(void)createNewHoleLabel:(NSString*)plistString andSetX:(int)x {
//SetX; 0 = P1, 1 = P2 etc.

UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(80 + 53 * x, 93 + 26 * integer, 50, 25)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:plistString ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

label.text = [dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hole %i", integer + 1]];

[label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
integer++;
[scrollview addSubview:label];
}
```

I hope you can help me. Please ask for further details if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `writeScore:forPlayer:`

```
plistpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Scores" ofType:@"plist"];
...
[plistdata writeToFile:plistpath atomically:YES];
```

You are trying to write to the the App's bundle which can not be done on the device. You should be writing the the Documents directory.

Comment: Nah, everyone makes mistakes like that.